# Remove maximize icon from DefaultDockable (Java, Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 DefaultDockable like this one: [image: DefaultDockable example]

Each one of them has a tittle bar and a maximize icon. The DefaultDockable already maximizes when double-clicked, so the maximize icon is useless and i want to remove it. How can I do that?

EDIT: 5 days passed, and still no ideas. Any help?

Comment: You might search the documentation for the term "decoration", used by some APIs.

Comment: I'll totally try that when i get some time, thanks! :)

Comment: ...I'm not seeing that DefaultDockable exists as a subInterface of Dock... I'm not seeing that it exists at all, really...